# The listStatusChanges API call in the Docusign SDK is not returning recently delivered envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

We poll for envelopes utilising the [`listStatusChanges`](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges) method from the Docusign SDK.

The `listStatusChanges` call is made with a From date to `datetime.now - 10` days with no other parameters.

If we send and complete the envelope within 10 days the completed envelope is picked up.

If we sent an envelope say 10 months ago and it completed 2 days ago liststatuschanges-10 days will not pick up the completed envelope.

What is the determining factor the API uses to decide whether status changes are returned?

Comment: What language; and is there a minimal reproduction that could help us reproduce what you're seeing? also. it's unclear without either of the above that this question isn't better suited for Docusign's support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that I don't have an answer to your specific question. You may want to consider the alternative of using Connect (webhooks) to receive faster notifications of changes, and more consistent change notifications.

Using AWS, Azure, Google Cloud or other vendors, you can set up your app and receive notifications behind your firewall with no firewall changes or DMZ access needed.

See the code examples for a [webhook listener](https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-aws) and the [behind-the-firewall worker](https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-worker-aws).